# Grouped nodes in OpenStreetMap with Overpass API

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Hy.I would like to query nodes gruped by some area. For example: how to get all nodes (e.g. peaks) for given area (eg. administrative boundary - country).

Something like join in SQL:
    SELECT n.*, a.name from node n LEFT JOIN area a ON n.area_id = a.id WHERE n.type = "peak"

Resoult would be something like:

```
{ features: [
 { 
   type: "node:",
   area: "slovenia"
   properties: {....},
   geometry: {...}
 },
 ...
]}
```

or maybe:

```
{ areas: [
 slovenia: {
  nodes: [
  { 
   type: "node:",
   area: "slovenia"
   properties: {...},
   geometry: {...}
  },
  ...
  ]
 },
 ...
]}
```

Is this even possible? Or should I first make 1 query for all areas and then for each area make another query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Area in area support is not yet officially available (see [this Github pull request](https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/pull/133) for some ideas how this might look like in the future), but you could use the approach described on the following help page:

https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/35976/add-reverse-geocoding-information-to-the-overpass-resulting-set

In particular I'd recommend to take a look at the following query: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/4FJ

It works with a single query but mixes sign posts with all areas this sign post is included.You should be able to easily adjust this to your tags / area. Note that a bit of post processing on the result may be required.

Probably the closest thing you're looking for is also described in the [Github pull request](https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/pull/133#issuecomment-56866641). This would print the area followed by all nodes in that area. But as I mentioned, this will only be available at some point in the future.

Sample output:

```
@oname  @id     name
area    3600062387      Landkreis Merzig-Wadern
node    313138635       
node    313150002       
node    313460474       
node    315050154       
node    431311279       
...
```